# How in yii make subquery for calculaion number of rows in related table in 1 request?

Tags: yii, subquery, cactivedataprovider

How in yii 1.1.7 using CDbCriteria and CActiveDataProvider to make subquery for calculaion number  of rows in related table in 1 request ?

In CodeIgniter I wrote like :

```
$CategoryFactory = ORM::factory('category');
$CategoryFactory->select( DB::expr(  ' ( select count(*) from `tour` where `tour`.`category_id` = `category`.`id` ) as related_tours_count ' ) );      
...
$category_result= $CategoryFactory->find_all();
```

Is there is similar way in yii 1.1.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I never used codeIgniter, but in Yii must define a Model and then use [countBySql method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#countBySql-detail)
or any other method of the [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord) class